How are we to view the coming of the Messiah in terms of years?
Most Christians use the Gregorian Calendar which puts us in 2024. According to the Hebrew calendar its 5784.
Most of us ( the church) believe the Messianic Prophesies/ the second coming being soon (around 2,000 years). Although the Jews don’t believe in Jesus as the Messiah I understand we are actually in the year 5784. How should we view the second coming in terms of years?
I know that for God one day can be a thousand years for men. Does that then mean we are wrong to say 2,000 years?
An overview of all Christian positions is needed for this question
The Jews believe that the Messiah will come 6,000 years after creation which is how they started their calendar years to begin with so their years seem far more accurate regardless of if Jesus isn’t their Messiah.

There are a lot of Christian perspectives on this - when you say "most of us believe... 2000 years) who is "us"?  I've never heard anything in particular for Orthodox or Catholic theologians.  So I'm guessing you're talking about some form of millennialism?

Thanks for your comment, I’m actually loooking for answers though. If you consider view points I’ve been taught by “us” (the church obviously) since the 1960s millennialism then I’m not sure I can help you there.

Ohh nevermind, I thought Millennialism  meant present-time.  I actually had to look it up. millennialism, the belief, expressed in the book of Revelation to John, the last book of the New Testament, that Christ will establish a 1,000-year reign of the saints on earth (the millennium) before the Last Judgment— but no it’s not that.

You ought to distinguish the dating methods a bit here. Comparing the year 2024 with 5784 is apples and oranges. The Jewish reckoning of 5784 is the year Anno Mundi, meaning years since the creation of the world, while the year 2024 is Anno Domini, meaning years since the birth of Christ.

In Catholicism AFAIK, 1000 years is not meant as precisely 999 years +1, but "a long time." We see other places where a number has a non-precise meaning, as in 40 days and nights (a long time), 144,000 missionaries (12x12 representing 12 tribes of Israel and 12 apostles meaning the unified Church, x 1000 meaning "a whole bunch.") So I think the question of whether it's 1000 or 2000 years wouldn't occur to us. I think lots of Protestant denominations would agree with us, but not literalists.

We've been in the "end days" for the last 2000 years. Anyone who thinks they can know anything more than that is kidding themselves. All the Biblical criteria for when Jesus will return apply just as well to every moment since Jesus ascended (except perhaps the one that the Gospel will go to every nation...)

Agreed. If even The Son of Man knows neither the day nor the hour, then why do we Christians waste so much ink on the subject? Just walk humbly with our God, and trust him to get the other stuff right.

Welcome to the site, please be explicit in which position you are coming from. Simply saying "the church" does not help. (I wish it did) Your position is not catholic, orthodox, and could possibly be any protestant branch that believes in Chiliasm (which was rejected as heresy about 1500 or so years ago) Also since no one can know the day or hour... and all this is just guessing based on numbers (numerology is also warned against strongly). While it is possible to answer this with a full overview, I humbly request that you express your position first. Which church, exactly how? Which prophecy?

Calm down. It was just a question. If this was considered heresy than it’s heresy. Simple. I don’t have any position except I follow JESUS. Period. There’s absolutely nothing “humble” about you request sorry. I’m not looking to guess any date or hour that’s explicitly against the word. It’s a simple question. Try not delving so deep into it. It’s not that important :) I promise

Technically, "no man knows the day or hour" (spoken by Jesus in the present tense around 30 AD) doesn't preclude the day being known by anyone sometime in the future. He didn't say "no man will know." But because of other statements, like His coming being as a "thief in the night," I think it's unlikely that the timing is something we can figure out just by adding numbers from the scriptures and Jewish or Christian tradition.

Thanks for an actual answer! :)

The first thing you should know is that the Jewish calendar isn't accurate. Second, there are discrepancies between the Hebrew OT (Masoretic text) and the Greek OT (Septuagint). The biggest differences are in genealogies of Genesis 5 & 11. Here are a couple of links that you may find enlightening:

https://www.bible.ca/manuscripts/Bible-chronology-charts-age-of-earth-date-Genesis-5-11-Septuagint-text-LXX-original-autograph-corrupted-Masoretic-MT-primeval-5554BC.htm

https://jewishbelief.com/5781-the-questionable-hebrew-calendar/

These were the facts. Now, we can speculate a little bit. It is true that many believe that the return of Christ will happen 2000 after His ascension. Jesus was crucified 40 years before the destruction of Jerusalem that took place in 70 AD. 40 is a well known biblical motive, symbolising a test. 40 cycles of jubilees give 2000. It is true, the Bible says:  "no man knows the day or hour". But we must treat that quote as an idiom meaning the precise date.

The Judeans two thousand years ago knew that they lived in the messianic times. They did not know the precise date (the day or the hour), though.  The century messianic frenzy in the Holly Land (from the rebellion of Judas the Galilean 6 AD to Bar Kokhba revolt 136 AD) shows us they were not far off.

Thank you for the external link. True not 100% accurate, much like anything else. But not far off either.

Ah a question about Chiliasm. My personal view is the Eastern Orthodox one. As such the response is actually really simple.
Amillennialism, Chiliasm is heresy.

Christ and the saints are reigning in heaven right now and someday, (we don’t know when), he will come again to judge the living and the dead.

Why don't we know though? What about that comment above?

Technically, "no man knows the day or hour" (spoken by Jesus in the present tense around 30 AD) doesn't preclude the day being known by anyone sometime in the future. He didn't say "no man will know." But because of other statements, like His coming being as a "thief in the night,"

Here is of course an interesting train of thought. However, the orthodox church would point out through Matthew 24:36 that if the Angels and Christ do not know the day or hour... how would we ever be able to know it until it happens?

But what about all of those amazing symbols in the visions??
Every vision stands for itself and has its own message. Through all of these images Christ speaks about the mysteries of God's will for the Church and the world (Rev. 1:1; 2:2-7; 5:1-5)
Exiled for the sake of the word of God to the island of Patmos, St. John, under the influence of the Holy Spirit, had visions in symbolic scenes which indicate, interpret and clarify things which are happening, or which are going to happen (it is indeed a book of prophecy) in the life of the Church (Rev. 1:1-11). In familiar images from the Old Testament, and from the current life situation in the Church, St. John saw and depicted for us the struggles of the Church of Christ against the manifold evils and the battles between the kingdom of God and the kingdom of the world. Behind the images of the beast and the prostitute woman, for example, are the persecutions by political and religious opponents of the Church, particularly the Roman Empire. Always hidden behind these opponents is the ancient serpent, the dragon, the devil, Satan himself, who deceives the nations and turns them against the Church.

But you asked about the interpretation of "years".
Numbers in the Book of Revelation are always symbolic. Only God knows the actual length of this period. (Matthew 24:36 again.)

The divine Fathers of the Church indicated in their writings that the one thousand year reign referred to in the book of Revelation signifies an infinite number of years, i.e. a kingdom that shall have no end. This we know well since from Holy Scripture it is clear that the Kingdom of Christ is not of this world (Jn. 18:36). In Holy Scripture it is clearly indicated that the Kingdom of Heaven is also the Kingdom of God or Kingdom of Christ, in so much as both Saint John the Forerunner and Christ Himself called it so. This Kingdom of Christ will be spiritual and will reign over the internal world of man, while externally being revealed in the righteousness, peace and joy of the Holy Spirit (Rom. 14:17). Christ Himself established this kingdom and explained in His parables how it will appear, who it will include and what power it will possess. His reign will not endure for a thousand years, but eternally (Lk. 1:33) -Elder Cleopa of Romania

For more info on that, click on the link to the article I quoted above.

Ultimately the position of the Orthodox church is the date of the Second Coming of Christ cannot be determined, as neither the angels nor even the Son of Man, as man, have been informed of it (Mat. 24:36-44), then surely neither can the date of the beginning of the millennium be determined nor any other end time events.
This is why the orthodox church (and the catholics) views all of this millenium stuff as heresy and it was condemned in the 2nd Ecumenical council in the year 381.

Regarding the disputed nature of the 2nd council in 381. Tatian, Tertullian, and Apollinaris all ended their lives in heresy and schism. Even if Chiliasm is not specifically refuted, the creed was updated to include the phrase "whose kingdom shall have no end" after "shall come again with glory to judge both the living and the dead". This makes clear that there would not be any temporary period, but an eternal one. (See Luke 1:32-33 and Daniel 7:14b)


Let us also look at Psalm 104[105]:8 "the word which he commanded for a thousand generations" (Book of praise, mixed with literal and symbolic language depending on the Psalm)

I mean... if you count starting from Adam we're at 100ish generations right? How does that make any sense?

Matthew 18:22 "...not seven times: but seventy times seven..." (Eyewitness account)

Are we only supposed to forgive people 420 times? No, we understand this is endless.

Luke 17:4 ... "you should forgive someone 7 times a day" (Gospel based on eyewitness accounts)

Do we stop forgiving at the 8th time in a day? No, we understand this is endless.

Judges 15:14-16... Samson killed 1000 philistines. (Historical book)

This might be a literal example, or it might be symbolic of a great number not usually possible for a man armed with a piece of bone.
Why would the book of Revelation (Prophetic/Symbolic) be something we would take literally?

I hope this answer will contribute to the general overview of responses, perhaps other denominations will speak up and state their version of this.
Peace be with you

I thought a position or church was needed? I’m confused. Nice try though!

What do you mean? I will gladly refine the answer if I didn't address something. I said the position and church at the start of the answer.

@Lyd I forgot to "at" you

It is disputed that the 2nd Ecumenical Council rejected Chiliasm as heretical. This article covers that issue well: https://francisgumerlock.com/wp-content/uploads/Millennialism-and-the-Early-Church-Councils.-Gumerlock.pdf

@Lyd ahh... I edited the answer. Even if the 2nd ecumenical council didn't flatout reject it... note what they did to the symbol of faith. "whose kingdom shall have no end" Also... why would the most symbol rich book of the bible be taken literally?

Not sure what’s going on? I already got an actual good answer by @ארקדיוס
…thanks though!

@Wyrsa - The linked article says that the addition of "whose kingdom shall have no end" was to oppose Marcellus' view of the Trinity, not oppose chiliasm. A quote: "On the subject of the Trinity, Marcellus taught that the distinctions in the
Godhead--the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit--were not eternal, but only temporal." Thus it is the eternal existence of Christ as forming a permanent distinction in the Godhead that was at issue.

I guess this was a waste of my time. Y'all already got it figured out. Post it as an answer then I guess.
